# UI-Router access the correct states when ending in '/'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states in my app, one is accessed by `localhost/web` and the other one `localhost/web/1`.

They work fine if they are accessed like above, but if I add a `/` at the end, the first one `localhost/web/` is going to access `localhost/web/1` templateUrl and controller. If I add `/` at the end of `localhost/web/1/` is going to redirect me to my default state.

I am using `nginx` to run my client, and I changed the location conf.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

The states:

```
.state('app.web', {
  url: '/web',
  views: {
    'container@': {
      templateUrl: '...',
      controller: '...',
    }
  }
}

.state('app.web.show', {
  url: '/:webID',
  views: {
    'container@': {
      templateUrl: '...',
      controller: '...',
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UI-Router` built-in solution is described here:

#### [How to: Make a trailing slash optional for all routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes)

> Q: How can I have my routes be activated when the `url` contains either a trailing slash or not?
>
> A: Set `strictMode` to false in your config block:

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)
```

Read more details in the [doc here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes)